# Как симитировать нажатие на кнопку в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, юнит-тесты

Мне нужно имитировать нажатие на кнопку в юнит тесте Unity, чтоб обработчик события кнопки сработал и я сравнил результаты. Я пробовал:

```
GameObject facebookBtn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); // Кнопка
bool res = ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerClickHandler>(
    facebookBtn, 
    new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current),
    ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
```

Насколько я понял нажатие срабатывает поскольку `res = true`, а обработчик кнопки не срабатывает. Мне кажется это из-за того, что это выполняется в editor mode хотя Unit tests по-другому в юнити не выполняются. Также получаю ошибку:

> Ignoring menu item NGUI because it is in no submenu.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с чем-то подобным?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не важен сам клик, а метод -- можно сам метод вызывать.

Если вам нужна именно имитация действия юзера, тогда лучше имитировать именно ее.

Если кнопка на клавиатуре:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/588786/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-keypressinput-in-code.html

Если нужна симуляция кником мышки на NGUI кнопку в юнити3д:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/564664/how-i-can-move-mouse-cursor-without-mouse-but-with.html